# Multitenant Lambda processing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

For a SaaS multitenant app how can I make sure that right file will reach the right user?

Workflow: user1 sends file.jpg to s3 bucket which triggers lambda function and should get back fileprocessed.jpg. user2 should get user2 files and so on.

Comment: Advice on [Building a Multi-Tenant SaaS Solution Using AWS Serverless Services](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/building-a-multi-tenant-saas-solution-using-aws-serverless-services/). Read about Tenant Isolation. Use policies to restrict a given client to DynamoDB items/state for that client's tenant ID.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of solutions to achieve the same:

- Either you create a state in a dynamodb table to make the link file / user
- Either you use a path in s3 with the user information
- Either you store the state in a file next to the real file (same folder?)
- You can imagine any other solution you like, everyone of it will rely either on convention or storage!

Comment: Thanks, what would be the most simple and effective (i.e. security-wise) way?

Comment: I would probably go with the state in file in s3, since you already use s3. Except if you also already have a ddb table.

Comment: In the "store state in s3" case, how would I check for the state? Is there a tutorial on this method?

Comment: You already know how to store the file the user sent with s3 I guess.

So you will create a text file with the relevant info in json (dict that you will dumps) and put it with boto3. And in the other function you will download it and convert it in dict with loads.

Comment: Isn't it a bad idea (security-wise) to have all user files in the same s3 bucket?

Comment: I believe that your user won’t access directly the s3 bucket. So it is simply a primary data store, like a db would be.